# Continuous function and nested compact spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces and $f:X \to Y$ be a continuous function. Let $K_n \subset X$ be a compact subspace of $X$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $K_{n+1} \subset K_n$. Prove that

$f(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} K_n)=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} f(K_n)$

My attempt at a solution:

The inclusion $f(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} K_n) \subset \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} f(K_n)$ is pretty easy: if $x \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} K_n$, then $x \in K_n$ for all $n$, so $f(x)$ is in $f(K_n)$ for all $n$, which means $f(x) \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} f(K_n)$ .

I suppose I have to use the two hypothesis (the function is continuous and the $K_n$'s are a sequence of nested compact spaces) to show the other inclusion, but I have no idea how to use these facts. I would appreciate any help or suggestion to prove the remaining inclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $y\in\bigcap f(K_n)$. Then for each $n$ there is an $x_n\in K_n$ with $f(x_n)=y$. The sequence $(x_n)_n\subseteq K_1$ has a cluster point $x\in K_1$ due to compactness. If $x\notin\bigcap K_n$, then there is some $k$ such that $x\notin K_l$ for $l\ge k$. But then $X-K_k$ would be an open neighborhood of $x$ not containing any of the later $x_l$, thus $x$ could not be a cluster point of the sequence. We conclude that $x\in\bigcap K_n$. Now what is the image $f(x)$?

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, $y=lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=f(x)$. , so $y \in f(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} K_n)$. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Well, not exactly. You only know that $x$ is a **cluster point** of $(x_n)$, so there is a subsequence converging to $x$. But this still means that $f(x)$ is the limit of the constant sequence $y$, so $f(x)=y$. You are welcome!